# How many of the available cores can I take up on a Mac without crashing the computer?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I need to run a parfor loop in Matlab and assign the number of workers to the loop.

Total Number of Cores: 10 (8 performance and 2 efficiency).

What is the maximum number of cores that I can take up, without crashing the computer and still being able to use the computer for browsing and email? Is leaving only 1 core free enough?

Below is an example in which 3 cores are selected.

```
n = 3 % Select the number of workers that you need and set n to that integer.

parpool(n) 

parfor

    i=1:n, c(:,i) = eig(rand(100)); 
    
end
```

Comment: Maybe [that](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/121136-programmatically-pre-detect-number-of-cores-available-to-parallel-computing-toolbox) will be of use

Comment: Thank you @BillBokeey However, I still do not know how many cores (of the available cores) I can use. Is there a rule of thumb to find out how many cores to leave free?

Comment: Why would you crash the computer if you use all cores? The computer is designed for you to use all its cores, that is the point of having them. You can create a pool of 20 workers and your computer should still not crash (they'd share a core, so they'd be slower, but they'll run nonetheless). If you create one fewer worker than you have cores, other programs will remain more responsive, but that doesn't mean you can't use the browser if you have 20 workers. The more relevant resource here is memory. If you run out, things will slow down to a crawl, and crashes could happen.

Comment: The computer is designed to have all its cores used. Whether OSX is designed to let the user tell it which cores to schedule jobs on is a different matter. I seem to remember that when I got my first quad core machine in 2012 that the Linux kernel got mad and crashed when I tried to make it run jobs on all 4 cores at once. I haven't tried since then, though.

Comment: One more thing: make sure your parallel pool is thread-based, not process-based. The process-based pool is the default. It starts up an instance of MATLAB for each worker. This uses a lot more memory (it's also slower because of the inter-process communication). Use thread-based parallelism whenever you can!

Comment: @CrisLuengo - thank you for this tip! Can you suggest any resources for doing this? My understanding is that I just increase the number of workers to be equal to the logical cores (I'm on a Mac, latest OS)...but unclear if that correct.

Comment: `parpool('Threads', 10)`. You can leave the "10" argument out, and set the default in your preferences. It likely is already set to 10. See [this document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html) to learn about the difference between thread and process-based parallelism in MATLAB.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks again! What I still can't find is how workers get assigned to cores (without threading). So, say I allocate 5 parallel jobs to two cores (core A and core B), does it just fill up the cores sequentially with jobs (A gets 3 jobs and B gets 2 jobs?)?

Comment: The OS distributes the processes and threads as it sees fit. For example, if you have a single active thread, it will be moved around from core to core to distribute the heat generation around the chip. There are ways to force a thread to remain in a specific core, but I don’t know exactly why that is useful or whether MATLAB uses that. In short, it is something you shouldn’t worry about. Whether you have 3 threads/processes running or 30, the OS will ensure they each get their fair share of compute time.